# Using reflection for fields

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is it better to use reflection in my case? I develop library for working with `vk` api. My code for base class that build URI for requests:

```
public abstract class VkApiMethod : IVkApiMethod
{
    private string _apiUri = "https://api.vk.com/method/",
                   _apiVersion = "5.92";

    public VkApiMethod(string AccessToken)
    {
        this.AccessToken = AccessToken;
        Fields = new string[] { };
    } 

    public string VkApiMethodName { get; protected set; }

    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public string[] Fields { get; set; }

    protected abstract string GetMethodApiParams();

    public string GetRequestString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}?access_token={2}&fields={3}{4}&v={5}", _apiUri,
                                                                         VkApiMethodName,
                                                                         AccessToken,
                                                                         ArrayToString(Fields),
                                                                         GetMethodApiParams(),
                                                                         _apiVersion);
    } 
}
```

`VkApiMethod` is a base class. Derived class must override `GetMethodApiParams()` method. `GetRequestString()` call `GetMethodApiParams()` to get `params` of derived class.
For example

```
class GetUsers : VkApiMethod
{
    public GetUsers(string AccessToken)
        : base(AccessToken)
    {
        VkApiMethodName = "users.get";
    } 
    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификаторы пользователей или их короткие имена.
    /// </summary>
    public string[] UserIDs { get; set; }

    protected override string GetMethodApiParams()
    {
        return string.Format("&user_ids={0}", ArrayToString(UserIDs));
    }
}
```

And another way without `GetMethodApiParams()` method using reflection:

```
public string GetRequestString()
{
    var @params = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
                  let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequestParamAttr), true)
                  where attr.Length == 1
                  select new
                  {
                      PropValue = p.GetValue(this),
                      AttrName = (attr.First() as RequestParamAttr).ParamName
                  };

    var _reqUriParams = "";
    foreach (var param in @params)
        _reqUriParams += string.Format("&{0}={1}", param.AttrName, param.PropValue);

    return string.Format("{0}{1}?access_token={2}{3}&v={4}", _apiUri,
                                                             VkApiMethodName,
                                                             AccessToken,
                                                             _reqUriParams,
                                                             _apiVersion);
}
```

Derived class example:

```
class GetUsers : VkApiMethod
{
    public GetUsers(string AccessToken)
        : base(AccessToken)
    {
        VkApiMethodName = "users.get";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификаторы пользователей или их короткие имена.
    /// </summary>
    [RequestParamAttr("user_ids")]
    public string[] UserIDs { get; set; }
}
```

What way is better to use?

Comment: Always avoid reflection – only use it if there is no other way.

Comment: Reflection is no readable and is a complex way.

Comment: What is your motivation to use reflection? I can not agree with comments above "always avoid" but in which way you think reflection is justifiable in your case?

Comment: but @AlexYu it seems reflection does not have application here as he just may want use reflection to write less code or wants remove  `GetMethodApiParams()` like he mentioned in question, anyway Reflection is useful when we don't know about types,members and methods in an assembly and want to write plugins,something like that and investigating objects during run-time which question does not any of that factors.

Comment: @Aria That's why I ask clarification from OP why he thinks reflection can be justifiable here